# How to retrieve all 'groups' from a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

From a given dictionary that looks as follows:

```
{
    'parent1': {
        'child1-1': {
            'element1': 'val1',
            'element2': 'val2'
        },
        'child1-2': {
            'element1': 'val1',
            'element2': 'val2'
        }
    },
    'parent2': {
        'child2-1': {
            'subchild2-1-1': {
              'subelement1': 'val1'  
            },
            'element2': 'val2'
        },
        'child2-2': {
            'element1': 'val1',
            'element2': 'val2'
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve all keys for the nested groups as follows:

```
'parent1':       ['child1-1', 'child1-2']
'child1-1':      ['element1', 'element2']
'child1-2':      ['element1', 'element2']
'parent2':       ['child2-1', 'child2-2']
'child2-1':      ['subchild2-1-1', 'element2']
'subchild2-1-1': ['subelement1']
'child2-2':      ['element1', 'element2']
```

Output may be in a new dictionary, ordering of the output is not important and all leaf elements should be ignored. The amount of nested levels should be arbitrary as nesting could potentially go on 'infinitely'.

This is my current code:

```
def dict_depth(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return 1 + (max(map(dict_depth, d.values())) if d else 0)
    return 0

group_dict = {}
def retrieve_groups(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict) and dict_depth(v) != 1:
            retrieve_groups(v)
            group_dict[k] = list(v.keys())

retrieve_groups(c)
print(group_dict)
```

Which returns the following:

```
{'child2-1': ['subchild2-1-1', 'element2'],
 'parent1': ['child1-1', 'child1-2'],
 'parent2': ['child2-1', 'child2-2']}
```

This clearly isn't complete as subgroups are missing. I feel like I'm overcomplicating this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does what you want:

```
def retrieve_groups(d, ret={}):
    ret.update({key: [subkey for subkey in value] 
                for key, value in d.items() if isinstance(value, dict)})
    for value in d.values():
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            continue
        retrieve_groups(d=value, ret=ret)

    return ret
```

where i use `ret` as mutable argument that is updated during the recursion. the rest should be straight-forward.

the output is:

```
{   'child1-1': ['element1', 'element2'],
    'child1-2': ['element1', 'element2'],
    'child2-1': ['subchild2-1-1', 'element2'],
    'child2-2': ['element1', 'element2'],
    'parent1': ['child1-1', 'child1-2'],
    'parent2': ['child2-1', 'child2-2'],
    'subchild2-1-1': ['subelement1']}
```

Comment: You're a magician. Thank you. Any good resource you can recommend for reading up on mutable arguments?

Comment: welcome! these might be worth reading: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/ and https://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm .